# Load all related object without naming tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy to build a REST API for the first time.
I'm trying to get a JSON representation of an object and all related objects without actually naming the tables (the schema will evolve regularly).

Let's have a Record with a foreign key to Person. On top of that, a many to many relationship with Fixtures:

```
class Record(Base, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'record'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    id_creator = Column(ForeignKey(u'person.id', ondelete=u'SET NULL', onupdate=u'CASCADE', match=u'FULL'), nullable=False)
    person = relationship(u'Person', primaryjoin='Record.id_creator == Person.id')


class Person(Base, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String)

t_many_fixture_has_many_record = Table(
    'many_fixture_has_many_record', metadata,
    Column('id_fixture', ForeignKey(u'fixture.id', ondelete=u'RESTRICT', onupdate=u'CASCADE', match=u'FULL'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('id_record', ForeignKey(u'record.id', ondelete=u'RESTRICT', onupdate=u'CASCADE', match=u'FULL'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
)

class Fixture(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fixture'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    record = relationship(u'Record', secondary=u'many_fixture_has_many_record')
```

How to generate an output that looks like this (I'm flexible):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "person": {
    "id": 12,
    "description": "a description"
  },
  "fixture": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I managed to get the list of objects referenced with a foreign key `list_of_dependant_objects = dependent_objects(my_record)` but I don't know how to approach the rest.

Any help is welcome. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's SQL behind SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy doesn't try to hide it from you. With this you have to specify list of tables you want to load from. And there's no term in SQL like "related" tables or "dependent" tables.

If you don't want to specify whole table structure, you might use an `autoload` attribute for a table as it [described](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) in SQLAlchemy documentation:

```
messages = Table('messages', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

BTW, you can use very advanced SQL to find out this. In most cases it doesn't worth a while as this SQL is database-specific and might change from one version of the same DB to another. Also you can read whole db schema and try to create a graph, but there could be links between schemas and databases you might not know about.